# Using PHP to parse XML with SimpleXML and having issues with Namespaces

Tags: php, xml, parsing, namespaces, simplexml

There's a lot of information on SO and PHP.net about using PHP to work with XML but I am having problems finding anything that shows how to work with a namespace in the same way my XML is set up.  I am not experienced with XML at all so it is quite possible I just don't know what I am looking for exactly when I try to google this whole thing.

This is what it looks like:

```
<entry>
    <id>16</id>
    <link href="/ws/1/h/all/16/" type="application/vnd.m.h+xml" title="m_h_title" />
    <published>2013-05-11T20:53:31.144957Z</published>
    <updated>2013-05-27T12:20:13.963730Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Discovery</name>
    </author>
    <title>m_h_title</title>
    <summary>
         A presentation of the substance of a body of material in a condensed form or by reducing it to its main points; an abstract.
    </summary>
    <myns:fields>
      <myns:field name="field_one"   type="xs:string" value="value_one"   /> 
      <myns:field name="field_two"   type="xs:string" value="value_two"   /> 
      <myns:field name="field_three" type="xs:string" value="value_three" /> 
      <myns:field name="field_four"  type="xs:string" value="value_four"  /> 
      <myns:field name="field_five"  type="xs:string" value="value_five"  /> 
    </myns:fields>
</entry>
```

And this is as far as I've made it...  (this was simplified a bit before I posted it)

```
$output = new SimpleXmlElement($response['data']); 

foreach ($output->entry as $entry) 
{ 
   $arr['id'] = (string) $entry->id;            // this is fine

   $arr['summary'] = trim($entry->summary);     // this is also fine

   print "\$entry->fields type: " . gettype($entry->fields);   // object


   foreach ($entry->fields as $field)   // this doesn't do anything, though 
   {
      $name  = (string) $field['name']; 
      $value = (string) $field['value']; 

      print "$name: $value <br/>";

      $arr[$name] = $value;  
   }  
}
```

If I var_dump $arr, it does hold correct values for ID and summary but I can't seem to get to any of the data in the actual fields.  I am going to keep playing with this... so if no one responds for a minute I might end up updating this post a million times with added "this is what I tried" code.

---

**ended up with this:**

```
 $output = new SimpleXmlElement($xml_response); 

 foreach ($output->entry as $entry) 
 {       
    $arr['id'] = (string) $entry->id; 
    $arr['summary'] = trim($entry->summary);  

     foreach($entry->children('myns', true) as $fields)       // myns:fields
     {       
        foreach ($fields->children('myns',true) as $field)    // myns:field 
        {   
           $name  = (string) $field->attributes()->name;
           $value = (string) $field->attributes()->value;

           $arr[$name] = $value;    
        } 
     }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account the namespaces, there's not enough information here to provide a working example for you - but take a look at Comment #2 at [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php#example-5370).

Actually, here's a quick example.

```
<?php
$xml = '<items xmlns:my="http://example.org/">
    <my:item>Foo</my:item>
    <my:item>Bar</my:item>
    <item>Bish</item>
    <item>Bosh</item>
</items>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($sxe->item as $item) {
    printf("%s\n", $item);
}

/*
    Bish
    Bosh
*/

foreach($sxe->children('my', true) as $item) {
    printf("%s\n", $item);
}

/*
    Foo
    Bar
*/
```

Anthony.

Comment: I can't get it to work - can you switch it so that the fields with a namespace are under/in a field without a namespace?  like `<items><my:item>foo</my:item><my:item>bar</my:item></items>`